# Default Done button on Android Mediacontroller

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I want done button in Android Mediacontroller as in iPhone Mediaplayercontroller by default. Is there any facility in Android Mediacontroller? I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, you are more likely to get the help you are looking for if you give more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish. And if you state what you've already tried and why/how it didn't work.

[The MediaController object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) does not contain a done button by default though. In order to add one all you'd have to do is subclass MediaController and add your own Button to it and handle the clicks to make them do whatever you like. Then you can call mp.setMediaController() and pass it your own custom MediaController instead of the default one.

Comment: Thanks Tim i have already made custom done button, but actually i wanted to know is there default done button in android mediacontroller as in apple mediaplayercontroller by default. Any way thanks again Tim for replying.